# Refresh datatable doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with a datatable after doing something with a row.

I have a CommandButton that's call a method and after doing differents procedures call to a Dialog to show the result.

After that, I use the event "handClose" to refresh the information of the datalist of datatable and finally I refresh the panel contains the datatable.

But, the problem is that de rows doesn't refresh correctly.

Here the code of the Datatable component

```
    <p:panel id="panelResultados">                                                      
    <p:dataTable id="tablaAvanzadas"  sortMode="multiple" var="solicitud" value="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.listaSolicitudes}" widgetVar="tablaAvanzadasWidgetVar"
                            selection="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.solicitudesSeleccionadas}" rowKey="#{solicitud.idSolicitud}" style="margin-bottom:0"
                            paginatorTemplate="{JumpToPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"                                 
                            rows="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.configurationTabla.paginacion.pagesize}" draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true"                
                            emptyMessage="#{ptf['comun.mensaje.sinResultados']}" paginator="true" reflow="true" 
                            paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" first="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.configurationTabla.paginacion.first}">
```

Here is the Command that starts all the cycle:

```
  <p:commandButton id="cmdButtonFirmar" rendered="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.filtroTabla=='P'}" value="#{ptf['btn.firmar']}" action="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.firmarSolicitudes}" />
```

Here is the code of the ajax of handleClose:

```
   <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{pc_ListadoSolicitud.handleClose}" update="form1:panelEstado form1:panelResultados"/>
```

The event code:

```
public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {     
    actualizarFiltroTabla(null);        
}
```

And the end of the method "actualizarFiltroTabla" I update the panel:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form1:panelResultados");
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `update` attribute of `commandButton`?

Comment: I've tried it but it does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem redirecting.
Here the code

```
public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {     
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "listadoSolicitud");
    return;
}
```